# Kapt: How to read annotation (and its parameters)

Tags: kotlin, kapt

Having a class:

```kotlin
@MarkerForKapt
@AnotherAnnotation(withParameter = "X")
class MyClass
```

And a processor:

```kotlin
class MyProcessor : AbstractProcessor() {

    override fun getSupportedAnnotationTypes() = setOf(MarkerForKapt::class.qualifiedName)

    override fun process(annotations: Set<TypeElement>, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment): Boolean {
  
        val element = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MarkerForKapt::class.java).single()
    

    }
}
```

How to read value `"X"` from `@AnotherAnnotation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add rt.jar to configuration:

`build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
    implementation(files("${System.getProperty("java.home")}/../lib/tools.jar"))
```

Processor:

```kotlin
import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol


    override fun process(annotations: Set<TypeElement>, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment): Boolean {
  
        val element = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MarkerForKapt::class.java).single()
    

        element as Symbol.ClassSymbol

        val annotation: AnotherAnnotation? = element.getAnnotation(AnotherAnnotation::class.java)

        val theX = annotation?.withParameter
    }
```